# why doesn't IIS have compression turned on by default

Tags: gzip, http-compression

i [am reading articles like this one](http://www.smallworkarounds.net/2009/01/aspnet-iis-tricks-using-gzip.html) [and this one](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html) to walk through the (tedius) steps to turn on gzip compression on IIS (6.0 in this case).  I don't understand why IIS would turn this all on by default. Who would not want to compress files going down to the browser ??

Comment: it's like with their browsers - 'we did this differently too'. I don't think anyone can give you any solid reason why it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who understands that compression doesn't always improve things wouldn't want it turned on by default.

It takes CPU time, and may not actually reduce the number of bytes sent significantly.

Comment: I agree John - in context of the era of IIS 6, the cost of compression was very high for high-throughput services - both in CPU and the memory required to buffer the stream ready for compression. Instead we offloaded this task to upstream network appliances, instead focusing on unbuffered responses running at wirespeed to the network appliance.